# How to prevent recipient from editing a document when signing with DocuSign?

Tags: c#, docusign-sdk

I've tried creating an envelope using the C# API and on Docusign, in both cases, the person who receives the link can edit the document, add fields etc.
How do I prevent others from editing the document?
I've checked the code of the examples but i can't find anything special which would disable them.
I've seen on SO a response about setting a different 'state' on the Signer, but it seems to be an outdated answer.
I've seen examples on the Docusign page where the user does not see any fields on the left, but I have no idea how to make it look like that.

In my case, I create the envelope the following way:

```
private async Task<EnvelopeDefinition> CreateEnvelope(DocusignSignatureRequest request)
    {
        EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        env.EmailSubject = request.EmailSubject;
        env.Documents = new List<Document>();

        foreach (var document in request.Documents)
        {
            string docBase64 = await GetBase64File(document.FilePath);
            env.Documents.Add(new Document()
            {
                    DocumentBase64 = docBase64,
                    Name = document.Name,
                    FileExtension = "pdf",
                    DocumentId = document.Id,
                    DocumentFields = new List<NameValue>()
            });
        }

        Signer signer1 = new Signer
        {
                Email = request.SignerEmail,
                Name = request.SignerName,
                RecipientId = request.SignerId,
                RoutingOrder = "1",
        };

        env.Recipients = new Recipients
        {
                Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1 },
        };
        env.Status = "sent";
        return env;
    }
```

I've tried without the list of fields as well, but same effect.